# Can't Install Xcode on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, xcode

I have tried 3.2.5, 3.2.6, 4.0.2, 4.2 etc and I get an install error immediately after providing credentials.  I provide username, password.  I am admin.  Then I get The "Installation Failed" error:

> An unknown installation error occurred.  The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail.  Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.

How can I find out what the problem is?

Comment: Do you have the last version of Snow Leopard?

Comment: and did you install this: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1512 (About Apple Software Installer Update 1.0.

This update addresses an issue that may prevent certain Apple software from installing. This update is recommended for all users running Mac OS X 10.6.8.)

Comment: @lupincho You should make that an answer. It fixed the problem for me!

Comment: @Pongus: I made that an answer; glad that it fixed your issue

Comment: AAAAAR.  So now I can finally install the thing that will let me install the thing that will let me install the thing that will let me install the thing that I actually need to install.  .. I AM SHAVING A YAK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install this: [Apple Software Installer Update 1.0.](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1512)

About Apple Software Installer Update 1.0: "This update addresses an issue that may prevent certain Apple software from installing. This update is recommended for all users running Mac OS X 10.6.8."

Comment: want to make thousands vote up. It saves my time because i had to give update to client.

Comment: Yes, that's very weird issue. I don't use SL anymore, but saw that download when looking for something else and remembered it as it is something that I haven't seen before.

Comment: "The installation failed" :( Even after this update. I tried to install Xcode 3.2.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.