# Make and Xcode for OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, xcode, make

I have OS X Snow Leopard and I need install `make` (this exists in Xcode). I don't have the DVD to install though.

On the [Xcode page](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) I don't find an old version of Xcode.

How I can get an old version of Xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Xcode 3

The latest **Xcode 3.2.6** (with the iOS SDK) is available under this link:

> https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg

You need to be signed up to the [free Apple Developer program](http://developer.apple.com/) in order for this to work, I guess. Note that this version will not be updated anymore. If you run into problems installing it, see this question: [Can't Install Xcode on OS X Snow Leopard](https://superuser.com/questions/410573/cant-install-xcode-on-os-x-snow-leopard)

A list of all downloads is also available. Just sign into the Apple Developer website and visit the following link:

> http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/downloads

Here, under "Developer Tools" (in the right sidebar), you'll find older versions of Xcode and additional tools.

Comment: Note that it's a 4.1GB download. I hope you're not in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one is right for you:

#### [OSX GCC Installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)

No need to install bulky Xcode just for `make`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried registering as a [Apple Developer for Free](https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/), it required you have an Apple ID.

Once you log in there then you will have to look around for Xcode 3.2.6 for SnowLeopard.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of Xcode can be downloaded from https://connect.apple.com; this requires a free (*not* the $99 Mac or iPhone developer subscription) developer registration at http://developer.apple.com.